# Can someone help explain some of the new SSIS 2012 properties?

Tags: ssis, bids

As someone who's learning SSIS, there are some new properties in **SSIS 2012** that I can't find any documentation/explanations for. Thus, I'm hoping someone can explain them:

In the Maintenance Cleanup Task, the BIDS property grid has a DeleteFromAllBricks property. What does that property control?

In the Back Up Database Task, I see the CopyOnlyBackup, IgnoreReplicaType, and UseExpiration (which is also present in 2008) properties. What are these properties for?

In one of my dtsx files, there's a Rebuild Index task with a SkipUnsupported property. What does SkipUnsupported do?

Note that none of these properties have their description fields set in BIDS and when searching online, I can't find any definitions.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I pinged some of the MS SQL Tech writers for input on these, I'll update if I hear from them. As you said, there isn't much on BOL for these topics.

- [DeleteFromAllBricks](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/subscriptions/microsoft.sqlserver.management.databasemaintenance.dbmaintenancefilecleanuptask.deletefromallbricks)
- [CopyOnlyBackup](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms191495.aspx) Doesn't break your backup chain. This one I'm familiar with-we have all our backups handled by an automagic backup product. Full backup on the weekends, differentials on the days. If I request that the DBAs take a backup before performing a production implementation, if they took a "regular" backup, that'd reset some bit in the backup tables which would cause the backup tool to think something has happened and it *must* take a full backup to get to a safe point. If you specify a copy only backup, it doesn't break that log chain and the storage folks don't chew us out ;)
- [IgnoreReplicaType](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/subscriptions/microsoft.sqlserver.management.databasemaintenance.dbmaintenancebackuptask.ignorereplicatype) I assume it has something to do with [Replica types](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms152531.aspx)
- [Expiration date](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms188697.aspx) Setting an [expiration dat](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms178062)e on a backup prevents it from being overwritten until it's expired.
- Skip unsupported features

Comment: Thanks very much for this information. Please do reply back if you hear more.

Comment: Note that UseExpiration is different from ExpirationDate. Does UseExpiration need to be true for ExpirationDate to be used?

Answer (score 1):

The following is a description for the SkipUnsupported property.

Indexes can be rebuilt online or offline. When rebuilding a table non-clustered index that requires being offline (doesn’t support online rebuild), if the task rebuild online option or the skip unsupported index  option (SkipUnspported property)  is not selected, the indexes are rebuilt offline. Otherwise,  the entire table indexes are not rebuilt for this specific scenario.

Comment: The above user works on the MS SSIS product documentation team so any answer she provides here will be far more authoritative than mine. ;)